# Is there standard terminology to describe these two different kinds of domain a relation can have?

Tags: terminology, relations, convention

When talking about **relations**, **injections**, **surjection**, etc… we usually consider two different sets of input to the relation. For example, the input sets might be $\{1, 2\}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

These two sets are like the **range** and **co-domain**, except that they are sets of input, not sets of output.
When I write math, usually refer to the two input sets the **small domain** and the **big domain**.
However, that is not standard.
I do not like to invent new terminology if there is already standard wording for such things.
Most math textbooks written in the last 50 years contain something like the following:

> We define a relation to be any set of ordered pairs.
> Let $R$ be the relation $\{ (1, 11), (2, 22) \}$
> Let the **domain** of $R$ be the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.
>
> Earlier in the book, we defined the **domain** of any relation to be the set of natural numbers which appear on the left of at least one ordered pair in the relation. For example, if $R$ = { (1, 11), (2, 22) } then the **domain** of $R$ is set containing 1 and 2 and nothing else.
>
> We now have that the domain of $R$ is simultaneously both $\mathbb{N}$ and is $\\{1, 2\\}$  That is a contradiction,  but we will ignore it.
>
> Next, we ask the student to prove or disprove that every element of the domain of the relation $R$ is an element of the domain of relation $R$.
> In other words, we ask the student to prove or disprove that:
> $\forall x \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \exists y \in \mathbb{N}: (x, y) \in \{ (1, 11), (2, 22) \}$

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection#Injection) articles on [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation), [injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), and [surjections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) usually have the same issues as the textbooks.

Mainly, the word “***domain***” used for 2 or 3 different things:

> 1. The $\text{domain}_1$ of $R$ is $\{a \in \mathbb{N}: \exists b \in \mathbb{N}: (a, b) \in R \}$
> 2. For any set $A$, if $A$ is a super-set of the $\text{domain}_1$ of $R$ then $A$ is a $\text{domain}_2$ of $R$. $R$ has lots and lots of $\text{domains}_2$
> 3. The **domain** $_3$ of relation $R$ is a very specific super-set of the set of things appearing on the left side of at least one ordered pair. The **domain**$ _3$ of relation $R$ is unique.

What words do contemporary mathematicians use to describe each type of **domain**?

Comment: "Most math textbooks written in the last 50 years contain something like the following" Really? The passage you give looks quite strange to me. Do you have an example of something like that occurring in a textbook?

Comment: There is indeed some sloppy writing around this topic, but in my experience it's not really what you describe. Rather, there's a lot of conflation, not between definitions of "domain," but between relations with the same *graph* (= underlying set of ordered pairs). Here "domain" follows your definition $3$ unambiguously, it's just that the author may be ambiguous about *which* relation is being referred to. (This is separate from the convention in set theory, where relations/functions are *just* sets of ordered pairs and do not come equipped with additional domain/codomain information at all.)

Comment: Your (3) is what happens when you formalise the category of all binary relations. The set-theoretic model of a binary relation has to be augmented with designations of the intended domain and codomain in that category.

Comment: @NoahSchweber One such book is **Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics** by Chartrand, Polimeni, and Zhang.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Another such book is *Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics* By Ethan D. Bloch

Comment: Some authors will insinuate that a relation $R$ is reflexive if and only if for every set $A$, if $R⊂A×A$ then ∀x∈A,(x,x)∈R. It is then provable that every relation is *NOT* reflexive. Some other authors insinuate that $R$ is reflexive if and only if ∃ set $A$ such that if $R⊂A×A$ then $∀x∈A,(x,x)∈R$. We can then prove that every relation is both reflexive and not reflexive. It all comes from not being clear what the domain is.

Answer (score 1):

Given some cartesian product of two sets $A \times B$ then $R \subset A \times B$ is a relation on $A \times B$. Any element of $A$ is in the domain of that relation. If you restrict yourself to $R$ then $\{a : (a,b) \in R)\}$ is the domain of $R$. The context typically tells you if you're dealing with the superset $A$ or the restriction but the difference is rarely material.

Comment: From your definition of relation, you could prove that the number $42$ is in the domain of every relation. Let $A$, $B$,and $R$ be sets such that $R \subset A \times B$. By definition, $R$ is a relation on $A \times B$. Note that $R \subset A \times B \implies R \subset (A \cup \{42\}) \times B$. By the definition of *relation*, $R$ is a relation on $(A \cup \{42\}) \times B$. By the definition of *domain*, any element in $(A \cup \{42\})$ is in the domain of relation $R$. Therefore, $42$ is in the domain of relation $R$.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon No, that's nonsense, $42$ would have to be an element of $A$ and that's not ensured. $A$ could simply be the characters of the alphabet or the utensils in my house which are not the number $42$. If you add some additional elements to a set it's no longer the same set. Changing which set you define the relation over changes the relation, obviously, but the set must be well-defined. Consider the set of pants and the set of shirts in my closet. I can define a relation "matches with" from shirts to pants and that relation only has shirts in its domain, none of which are a number.

Comment: I am aware that it is absurd to say that the number $42$ is in the domain of every relation. However, it is provable using your definition of relation. My point was that your definition of relation is not good. If you define a relation in such a way that it can be proved that every relation $R \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ has $42$ in its domain, then you have a very silly definition of relation.

Comment: A mathematical definition of *bread* and your intuitive notion of what *bread* is might be different. It is difficult to prove mathematical statements about *bread* using anything other than the formal definition of *bread*. So, you better make sure that your formal definition is spot on.

Comment: I see that you seem to be using two different ideas about what a "***relation***" is: your informal intuitive notion of a ***relation*** is tells you that not all relations have the number $42$ in their domain. However, your formal definition of relation is sufficient to prove that all relations have the number $42$ in their domain.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon It's not provable using my definition of relation. You've made up some nonsense and attributed it to me but it's your nonsense.